# Won't filter update query by id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a code for a backend part of a website that pulls 'quicklinks' and allows them to be edited in the panel. When I don't add the 'WHERE' clause to the SQL it updates ALL quicklinks, however when I filter by ID it just doesn't work.

```html
<?php

    $query = "SELECT id,title,picture,link,alt,button,active FROM quicklinks" or die("Error!:" . mysqli_error($link)); 
    $result = $link->query($query); 
    $title = $_REQUEST["title"];
    $picture = $_REQUEST["picture"];
    $id = $_REQUEST["id"];
?>
<?php 


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
        if (isset($_REQUEST['update']))     
        {
        mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE quicklinks SET title='$title', picture='$picture' WHERE ID='$id' ");
        }
  echo "<form method='post'><div id='ql" . $row["id"] . "' class='modal fade' role='dialog'> <div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button><h4 class='modal-title'>Editing " . $row["title"] . "</h4></div><div class='modal-body'> 
<div class='input-group'>
            <span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Quick Link ID is: </span>
  <input type='text' name='id' class='form-control' value='" . $row["id"] . "' disabled='disabled'></div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Title: </span>
<input name='title' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["title"] . "'> </div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Link: </span>
<input name='link' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["link"] . "'> </div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Image URL: </span>
<input name='picture' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["picture"] . "'> </div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Image Alt Text: </span>
<input name='alt' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["alt"] . "'> </div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Button Text: </span>
<input name='button' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["button"] . "'> </div></br></div>
<div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button><input name='update' type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Apply'></div></div></div></div></form>"; 
} ?>
```

Comment: `ID='$id'` to `id=$id`

Comment: What means `doesn't work.`? Check for errors after executing a query.

Comment: @phplover I've tried both ID and id and get the same result, the post is made but the query obviously doesn't apply as if it can't find any results that match. No errors at all.

Comment: why do you have the query inside the while loop ?

Comment: Because I tried to get it to identify the ID without needing a where clause by putting it inside the while loop, therefore applying the query to every result individually. That was the hope anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is small letter in database then you should write it as it is in the query. Also if it is integer remove the quotes.

```
mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE quicklinks SET title='$title', picture='$picture' WHERE id=$id ");
```

**Edit**

I found that your code is actually messed up. Here is a modified code

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT id,title,picture,link,alt,button,active FROM quicklinks" or die("Error!:" . mysqli_error($link)); 
    $result = $link->query($query); 
    $title = $_REQUEST["title"];
    $picture = $_REQUEST["picture"];
    $id = $_REQUEST["id"];

    if ($_GET['do'] == "update") {
        mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE quicklinks SET title='$title', picture='$picture' WHERE id=$id ");
    }
?>
<?php 


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 

  echo "<form method='post' action='?do=update' ><div id='ql" . $row["id"] . "' class='modal fade' role='dialog'> <div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button><h4 class='modal-title'>Editing " . $row["title"] . "</h4></div><div class='modal-body'> 
<div class='input-group'>
            <span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Quick Link ID is: </span>
  <input type='text' name='id' class='form-control' value='" . $row["id"] . "' disabled='disabled'></div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Title: </span>
<input name='title' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["title"] . "'> </div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Link: </span>
<input name='link' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["link"] . "'> </div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Image URL: </span>
<input name='picture' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["picture"] . "'> </div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Image Alt Text: </span>
<input name='alt' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["alt"] . "'> </div></br>
<div class='input-group'>
<span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>Button Text: </span>
<input name='button' type='text' id='inputHelpBlock' class='form-control' value='" . $row["button"] . "'> </div></br></div>
<div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button><input name='update' type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Apply'></div></div></div></div></form>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: I've tried both ID and id and get the same result, the post is made but the query obviously doesn't apply as if it can't find any results that match. No errors at all.

Comment: @Jack check it now, I moved the update query outside the loop, and made a request for update which I couldn't find in code

Comment: Afraid that still hasn't worked, it still doesn't update any record.

Comment: @Jack try changing `$_REQUEST[]` with `$_POST[]` and get `$_GET[]`

Comment: Tried that just now, didn't work. Didn't update any records, no error and it made the post.

Comment: Added the print, doesn't give an error. Like I said.